# Datatable from Primefaces, rtl support

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I use datatable from Primefaces 3.5 library for Hebrew and therefore I need right to left support.
Actually I have done it for whole project by using

```
body{
direction:rtl;
}
```

everything fine except buttons: prev, next and first, last on datatable, now they showing in reverse order, like this:
[image]

How can I turn it in reverse order? I thought to do it by using css rotate or flip but it cause to another formatting problems, so I'd like to check if there any other appropriate way?
I tried use dir="rtl" in datatable but I haven't seen any difference.
Thank you.